# Chrome.webRequest API - requestBody always undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use the webrequest api in my Chrome extension. Using the following block of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        console.log(details.requestBody);
    },
    {urls: ["https://myurlhere.com/*"]}
);});
```

The console shows me that requestBody is undefined. If I log details by itself, I can inspect the details object, but I can't seem to find requestBody object anywhere.

Is my syntax wrong? I did some searching and found a couple other examples and it seems like it should be working the way I have it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What request are you making? If it's a GET request for example it makes perfect sense that the request has an empty body.

Comment: "**requestBody**: Contains the HTTP request body data. *Only provided if `extraInfoSpec` contains 'requestBody'.*" Add the one-element array `['requestBody']` as a third argument.

Comment: Get rid of jQuery. There's absolutely no need to wait for the domready event before binding the webRequest events.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must specify ['requestBody'] as the third parameter of addListener. For example:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        console.log(details.requestBody);
    },
    {urls: ["https://myurlhere.com/*"]},
    ['requestBody']
);
```

[The documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#event-onBeforeRequest) says:

> requestBody ( optional object )
>
> ```
> Contains the HTTP request body data.
> *Only provided if extraInfoSpec contains 'requestBody'.*
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works. I figured it was me screwing something simple up.

Comment: I am getting this error: ´Uncaught Error: Invalid value for argument 2. Property '.0': Value must be one of: [requestHeaders, blocking]´ for using requestBody there. I have chrome 36+

Comment: @Dandy It's only available in the onBeforeRequest event.

Answer (score 2):

Note that adding [`requestBody`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#property-details-requestBody) to `addListener()` would work, **provided** the request actually has a request body.

Most HTTP requests do not have any request body. In other words, getting `undefined` for `e.requestBody` is **normal** if the request does not have a request body.