# How to get post data in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get post data in a simple chrome extension, but it doesn't work:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function(details) {
if (details.method == "POST") {
            var postData=details.requestBody.raw; 
            console.log(postData);
        }
return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

I am using this site to test the extension:

https://mobile.onlinesbi.com/sbidownloader/DownloadApplication.action

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome.webRequest API - requestBody always undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017947/chrome-webrequest-api-requestbody-always-undefined)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this was asked so long ago, but in case anyone else comes across this same problem, I found the answer.

You're using the listener **onBeforeSendHeaders**, when the only listener that supports viewing the POST data is **[onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest)**. However, you also need to supply an extraInfoSpec of "requestBody" to the third argument of **.addListener**. An example is below.

```
/* The Web Request API */
const WEB_REQUEST = chrome.webRequest;

WEB_REQUEST.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(details.method == "POST")
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```